# How to Represent a PHP Closure in YAML?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, silex

I'm developing a PHP application using Silex and YAML.

Now I want to represent a PHP closure using the YAML language concept. What's the best way? There's a way to do that?

The following code is an example of what I want to "translate" to YAML.

```
'users' => function () use ($app) {
    return new UserProvider();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what Symfony does: you first define your User Provider as a service. With Silex you can do it with:

```
$app['my_user_provider'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new UserProvider();
};
```

Then, in your yaml configuration, you pass the service id that you want use. Something like:

```
security:
    user_provider: my_user_provider
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is asking how to define a service, not how to use one.  The Symfony container allows you to define services using yaml.  The Pimple container (which Silex uses) does not.

Comment: Actually I don't know if I was clear. I'm setting up a firewall using yaml, so I want to represent something like this:

`$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'users' => function () use ($app) {
            return new UserProvider();
        }
    ),
);`

Comment: No, you were clear. You just need to parse the yaml and compile your DIC.